# I am getting this error when i perform make on codeblocks source code

Tags: makefile, codeblocks

configmanager.cpp:39:44: error: wx/mac/corefoundation/cfstring.h: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

The compilator can't find the cfstring.h file. Try reinstall codeblocks.

Comment: Reinstalled but problem is still there I have downloaded the source code from this link http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/25 and I am using Macbook pro

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you are creating the file in *documents* or other folder.
**Create the file in your Desktop and while giving it a name don't include space in it**, click build and run, the terminal will open with the output. It worked for me at least, then you can move it to your desired folder.